# Select form data in multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

i have a php loop like this:

```
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>

    <form action="" method="post" name="my-form" id="my-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="<?php $row['user_id']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

It will output a form on each loop.

Here is my javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("appointment-single-form").onsubmit = function (e) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var queryString = $('#appointment-single-form').serialize();
    console.log(queryString); // output to console: user-id={user's id from the specific form that was clicked/submitted}
}
```

Depending on the form clicked/submitted, I need to get the form values using javascript.

**Question:** Only the first form is working because `getElementById` only workes for one id. how can i make it so that I can click on any form? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. Idea is use a common class for each form and attach submit event on that class.

```js
// Attach submit event on class, that is common for each form
$('.my-forms').on('submit',function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var curObj = $(this),queryString = curObj.serialize();
  console.log(queryString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form1" id="my-form" class="my-forms">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form 1">
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form2" id="my-form" class="my-forms">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form 1">
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form3" id="my-form" class="my-forms">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="3">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form 1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `jquery` like this  .Better use `tagname` or `classname` instead of ID of the form .Because `Id` is a unique

```
$(document).on('submit' ,'form',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 var query = $(this).serialize()
 console.log(query)
})
```

***Example***

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = $(this).serialize()
  console.log(query)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form" id="my-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="<?php $row['user_id']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form" id="my-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="<?php $row['user_id']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<form action="" method="post" name="my-form" id="my-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="user-id" id="user-id" value="<?php $row['user_id']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```